# Wireshark - see only multicast and broadcast traffic

Tags: wireshark, network-traffic

I can see only multicast and broadcast traffic from other users. I can`t see other packages.

I use wirless network card set in promiscuous mode.

What can be wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Change it to monitor mode. You will see all other traffic in this mode.

Comment: Nothing change.